# Common words filtering

Tags: mysql, select, filter

I am trying to create a "filter by letter" functionaly in php and database server `mysql`.
Table;

```
+-----+---------------------+
| nid | title               |
+-----+---------------------+
|   1 | Home and Services   |
|   2 | Health and services |
|   3 | Health and Medical  |
|   4 | Health and Allergy  |
|   5 | Stroke Services     |
+-----+---------------------+
```

But I want to filter out common words like "and" "services". So for example if user were to filter by letter 'S' it should return "Stroke Services" but should exclude "Home and Services" and "Health and services".

How can I acheive this? Here is my current query;

```
SELECT nid,title FROM node_field_data WHERE BINARY title LIKE "%S%%" AND BINARY title NOT LIKE "%Services%";
```

But it excludes "Stroke Services" too. Please help.

Comment: Just sit and think what your filter should do. Write it down. Finally, translate it to SQL query.

Comment: [Regexp_like](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/regexp.html#function_regexp-like) will possibly help you. SQL pattern matching with regular like is not that great. Also `NOT LIKE "%Services%"` should be something like `NOT LIKE "%and _ervices%"` - I am not sure that would work though

Comment: It is a bit difficult to devise a filter criteria, where you sometimes want to exclude a certain word, but in other cases you want to include it. Also, your current method requires you to manually design patterns (or combination of patterns) for every exclusion criterion. I don't think that is sustainable. You may want to look into boolean fulltext searches and providing list of stopwords.

Comment: Why not create a column that contains the "allowed" parts of that string, and update it on changing the `title` column? That could make the query to filter the rows much easier

Answer (score 0):

I was able to achieve this in single query. Actually I had three filter criterias;

1. Get all the titles starting with selected letter e.g. 'A'.
2. Get all the titles with any of the words in them starting with letter e.g. 'A'.
3. Ignore the common words like 'and', 'or', 'at', 'the' etc.

Divided these in two groups in my mysql query. (Group 1 checks for criterias #1 and #2) AND (Group 2 meets the criteria number #3). Following is the query for any one looking for something similar.

```
SELECT nid, title FROM node_field_data WHERE (BINARY title LIKE "A%" OR BINARY title LIKE "% A%%") AND (title NOT REGEXP "and|or|at|the")
```

In my case, content moderators were given a facility in the CMS where they could define the common words to exclude for each letter. Like the following;

```
A|and,at,again
C|care, can, could
S|services
```

etc...

Comment: This is not going to work as you expect: first of all, "random" will match "and". Also, you require that the title *does not contain the word 'and'*. So, "Me and Annie" will *not* match "word starts with A *and title does not contain and*" because the title *does* contain *and*.

In this example, "Random Cancellation Association" will turn out as **not containing any words starting with A** (and not containing any words starting with C)... which is obviously untrue.

Comment: Thanks for you help, I will give your query a shot. But mine worked fine here you can see it in action: https://ibb.co/2q6JzsT. The only thing that concerns me now is the "random" example you gave. Thanks for that, I guess I will have to tweak me regexp a bit to counter that.

Comment: I am... confused! The image you supply shows the query **not working**! You ask for items beginning with "M", and the item #7 ("MySQL and again...") is *not* shown in the output! If that is the desired result, then my method needs revising.

Comment: @LSerni, no it didn't show "MySQL and again..." thats what I emphasized on in the gif. If you review again careful at first all the records are shown and when I provide it letter 'M' the ID # 7 was gone because it contains 'and' as per the criteria number 3 it should exclude it hence it did.

Comment: I see. My bad, and sorry; it is a criterion I had never encountered, so I misunderstood it (I confirm that my solution did not work - so, I deleted it - as it ignored the nullwords "and", "or" etc. but matched the others, instead of ignoring all text containing the nullwords anywhere). For having "and" not match "random", you can use `NOT REGEXP '\\b(and|or|services)\\b'`, with \\b being the word-boundary match.

Comment: For the sake of clarity, though, I think it would be best to reword `3. Ignore the common words like 'and', 'or', 'at', 'the' etc.` into `3. Ignore **all titles** containing common words like...`, and possibly also include the example you gave in the comments: when looking for *titles containing words starting with M*, the title "MySQL and something" should not be found, while "MySQL something else" should.